# Why cv2.imread returns none when using django python?

Tags: python, django, opencv

I use opencv-python in django, but when I use **cv2.imread**, it just returns **nonetype**. How can I solve this problem?

````
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework.views import APIView
from rest_framework import status
from . import serializers
from .serializers import call_serializers
from .apps import BmiEstimationConfig
import pickle
from skimage import io

class BMIEstimationView(APIView):
    serializer_class = serializers.call_serializers

    def post(self, request):
        serializer = serializers.call_serializers(data=request.data)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        file = request.FILES['file']

        import cv2
        image = cv2.imread(file)
        print(image)```

got this :
> TypeError: bad argument type for built-in operation
````

Comment: Show us the code that's involved in this error. Show what you're passing to `cv2.imread`.

Comment: need more details

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure the syntax of the cv2.imread()

```
Syntax: cv2.imread(path, flag)

Parameters:
path: A string representing the path of the image to be read.
flag: It specifies the way in which image should be read. It’s default value is cv2.IMREAD_COLOR

Return Value: This method returns an image that is loaded from the specified file.
```

and also please provide full path of your image

to see the examples [click here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-opencv-cv2-imread-method/)

example pic:
[image]

Comment: i think if we dont spesific the flag, flag will be automatically set to default(1) right? to make sure it, i have try with adding the flag, but still not working @sourab maity

Comment: please see the above pic, yes it automatically set

Comment: how if we upload image from django?it has not been path, right? how to solve it? is it necessary to save first? or we can process without save it first? @sourab maity